# Drupal7 Multilanguage

Tags: drupal-7, multilingual

Can you recommend a good way to implement Multilanguage + drupal 7 ? provide good tutorial link or any reference site.

How can we set bellow things in Multilanguage?

- node
- taxonomy
- Menu
- View
- Panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions in [this tutorial](http://drupal.org/node/275705).

It works fine for Drupal 7 and 6.